# Dropdown menu not stable

Tags: html, css

I am working on the following project:

```css
/* Second Bar */

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 padding: 20px 40px;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav {

 font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a{
 display: inline-block;
 color: #4e5359;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:hover{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 color: white;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a.selected{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 color: white;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}

/*Dropdown menu*/
.dropbtn {
     cursor: pointer;
 }

 .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     margin-top: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 99;

 }

 .dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: inherit;
 }

 .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-top: initial; 
    padding-bottom: initial; }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 }
```

```html
<div class="header-second-bar">
   <div class="header-limiter">
    <nav>
     <span class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Home</a>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#" style="display: block;">Men</a>
       <a href="#" style="display: block;">Women</a>
      </div>
     </span>
                  
     <a href="#" style="color: pink;">Blog</a>
     <a href="#" style="color: pink;">Promo</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Everything was working fine, but when I implemented the dowpdown menu, I start having a bug when I tried to hover the dropdown list `Men` and `Women`. I think it is due to the `padding-top` applied to `.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:hover`

I also don't want to remove it because the others button `Blog`, `Promo` need it.

How can I solve the problem without removing the `padding-top` applied at `.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:hover`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1; 
}
```

Removing these lines from `.dropdown-content a:hover` makes it work

```
padding-top: initial; 
padding-bottom: initial;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the below css for dropdown  elements `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a { padding: 12px 16px;}`
Please see the updated fiddle, hope this will help

```css
/* Second Bar */

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 padding: 20px 40px;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav {

 font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a{
 display: inline-block;
 color: #4e5359;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:hover{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 color: white;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a.selected{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 color: white;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}

/*Dropdown menu*/
.dropbtn {
     cursor: pointer;
 }

 .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     margin-top: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 99;

 }

 .dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: inherit;
 }

 .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-top: initial; 
    padding-bottom: initial; }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
 }
         
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a { padding: 12px 16px;}
 .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 }
```

```html
<div class="header-second-bar">
   <div class="header-limiter">
    <nav>
     <span class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Home</a>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#" style="display: block;">Men</a>
       <a href="#" style="display: block;">Women</a>
      </div>
     </span>
                  
     <a href="#" style="color: pink;">Blog</a>
     <a href="#" style="color: pink;">Promo</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of removing the redundant code that makes the problem, this solution kinda hacks around it. See @Keiwan's answer. It simply faces the problem, removes the redundant code and makes the solution a lot more elegant.